# Mixing ng-switch with input causes loss of focus

Tags: angularjs

I am facing a problem involving `ng-switch` and forms. I need your help/advice to find a workaround for what seems to me a bug.

I wrote this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvverde/hyLXT/) to exemplify what happens. 
If you try to change the value of any input control you lose the focus as soon as you type a single character. Try to change the value in the field 'c', for example, to 2013.

This is the code.

HTML

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
  {{list}}
  <form>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="(k,v) in list">
        <div ng-switch on="k"> 
          <span ng-switch-when="b">B:<input ng-model="list[k]"/></span>
          <span ng-switch-default>{{k}}:<input ng-model="list[k]"/></span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

And the controller

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.list = {
        a: 0,
        b: 1,
        c: 2
    };
}
```

Any suggestions?

---

*Edited after sza answer*:

My real problem is a far more complicated than the example above. The sza's answer solves the problem above, however the problem (partially) stills if we change the code for something like this

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
  {{list}}
  <form>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in list">
        <div ng-switch on="type_of(item.value)"> 
          <span ng-switch-when="object">B:do something later</span>
          <span ng-switch-default>{{item.key}}:<input ng-model="item.value"/>
          </span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

and controller to

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.list = [{
        key: 'a',
        value: 0
    }, {
        key: 'b',
        value: [{key:'ba', value: 10}, {key:'bb', value: 11}]
    }, {
        key: 'c',
        value: 2
    }];
    $scope.type_of = function(val){
        return typeof val;
    }
}
```

With this code I still lose the focus after first input. Curiously if clicking on it for a second time it works as expected. Here is the [jsfiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/jvverde/Lg7L9/)

---

*Edited again*

Ok, I think I understand what is happen as pointed out by sza. If ng-switch depends of anything pointed by a ng-model attribute it seems to re-evaluate switch scope every time a user interaction occurs on some of those inputs.

Here is a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jvverde/EVyCh/) (and a little bit more complex) where the ng-switch does not depend on anything "changeable".

```
<script  type="text/ng-template" id="list.html">
  <div ng-switch on="item.type"> 
    <span ng-switch-when="object">
      <span ng-repeat="item in item.value" ng-include="'list.html'"></span>
    </span>
    <span ng-switch-default>{{item.key}}:<input ng-model="item.value"/>
    </span>
  </div>
</script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
  {{list}}
  <form>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in list" ng-include="'list.html'"></li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
```

and controller

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.list = [{
        key: 'a',
        value: 0
    }, {
        key: 'b',
        type: 'object',
        value: [{key:'ba', value: 10}, {key:'bb', value: 11}]
    }, {
        key: 'c',
        value: 2
    }];
    $scope.type_of = function(val){
        return typeof val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative I can come up with is to change your data model to key-value pairs like this

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.list = [{
        key: 'a',
        value: 0
    }, {
        key: 'b',
        value: 1
    }, {
        key: 'c',
        value: 2
    }];
}
<li ng-repeat="item in list">
    <div ng-switch on="item.key"> 
         <span ng-switch-when="b">B:<input ng-model="item.value"/></span>
         <span ng-switch-default>{{item.key}}:<input ng-model="item.value"/></span>
    </div>
</li>
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WvRgH/)**</kbd>

The problem of your approach could be related to the change of model list[k] triggers the `repeater` to refresh the DOM, since `K` or `V` will be re-evaluated.